# Incremental Training of a Keras Model with Sequential Data Chunks: Is it a viable approach?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a project that involves training a machine learning model using Keras on a dataset where each chunk is a distinct sequence. Due to the nature of the data, merging all the chunks into a single dataset would break the sequential integrity, hence I am considering an incremental training approach where each chunk is fed to the model in a sequential manner using a for loop:

```
for datafr in train_dfs:

x_train = datafr.loc[:, datafr.columns != 'classID'].to_numpy()
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

y_train = datafr.loc[:, 'classID']

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, callbacks=[early_stopping])
```

In this code snippet, train_dfs is a list of DataFrame objects, each representing a chunk of the training data. The model.fit() method is called within the loop for each data chunk.

Here are my questions:

1. When I call model.fit() for the first chunk of data, is the model training "finalized" at the end of this call, or does the model continue to update its weights with each subsequent call to model.fit() on new data chunks?
2. Is this approach a sensible way to maintain the sequential integrity of the data while training? Are there better alternatives for training on sequential data chunks in Keras?
3. How would this approach impact the testing and evaluation of the model? Would it be necessary or beneficial to test the model on each data chunk separately, or should testing be done after all chunks have been processed?

Any insights or recommendations on handling sequential data chunks in Keras for training, testing, and evaluation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I fail to  see why "merging all the chunks into a single dataset would break the sequential integrity", specially as your code is basically doing the same with batch size of one.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy each DataFrame in `train_dfs` is its own sequence. Mixing them or splitting them like usual would mess up the order of events in each sequence, which I want to keep intact while training and testing. So, I'm using the for loop to train on each DataFrame one by one, treating each as a separate sequence.

Comment: You are definitely confused, because having samples of sequences, and then making a single numpy array, does not mean you mix the sequences. The expected shape is (samples, timesteps, features).

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I indeed am confused a little. It's clearer to me now I think. In my case:

Samples: These are each of my experiments or sequences. Each one is its own piece of data within the 'master' dataframe.

Timesteps: This is the number of steps or points in each of my experiments. They all have the same number of steps.

Features: These are the details I measure at each step, like the columns in my data (except for the target or label columns).

Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy So, when I reshape my data for the RNN, I'm not mixing up my experiments. I'm just arranging them so the RNN understands them, but I'm keeping each experiment separate and in order, correct?

For other kinds of data, like daily stock prices, you can choose different numbers of timesteps and samples. But for my experiments, each one has to stay as it is, right? Thanks for helping me so far